# pygtk property and signal inheritance failing at grandparent level

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

EDIT New information at end of post.

Long story short, I need to add multiple methods and properties to most of the gtk widget family.  Many the same, many widget specific.  End result is that I need to subclass gtk.Widget, gtk.Object, and several specific widgets (Entry, Label, TextView, for example).

My problem is this.  When I create new properties in MyObject, MyWidget, and then in MyWindow, I write code to test MyObject, and properties (and signals) are present.

Then MyWidget inherits from MyObject, and gtk.Widget.  All properties and signals present and accounted for.

MyWindow then inherits from MyWidget and gtk.Window.  All the properties and signals from MyObject are gone.

The objects and signals are being created in the class definition using

`__gsignals__ = {<much data goes here>}
__gproperties__ = {<lots goes here>}`

and calling `gobject.type_register(MyClass)` from the main body level of the importable file after the class is defined.

Wrote several test variations of this, calling super() versions of init, specific inits (`gtk.Widget.__init__(self)`), and `self.gobject_init()`, and even tried `gtk.Widget.__gobject_init__(self)` all of them seem to lose the grandparent level of properties and signals (or worse).

I have come to the conclusion that I do not properly understand how to instantiate gtk classes using sub-classed widgets.  The article on sub-classing gobject (http://www.pygtk.org/articles/subclassing-gobject/sub-classing-gobject-in-python.htm) has been my main guide in the past, and while it mentions this issue, the explanation is to vague to help me (or I am to dense to get it).

Would someone be kind enough to point me to, or show an example of grandparent level inheritance of signals/properties that works?  I cannot find any via google.

Also helpful might be an explanation of what `__gobject_init_` does (how it does it).  I could write custom versions of this if need be, but I cannot find any docs on it.

(I am writing this from church and do not have any actual code with me I could post, Sorry.)

***UPDATE ONE:***

Okay sample code illustrating the problem, which I now realize is worse than I originally thought.  Inheritance is getting lost even at parent level.

Two code samples area attached, both are the same.  The first is human readable (pep8), and can be copy pasted into a document and executed.  It runs but offers illustrative output after the window is destroyed, explaining the issues, and proving they exist.

The second is less readable, but is the same code formated for copy pasting straight into the python interpreter.

First code set:
Output from this code indicates that no inheritance of signals or properties is occurring.

```
import gtk, gobject, pygtk

pygtk.require("2.0")


class DummyClass(gtk.Object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dummycode = None
        gtk.Object.__init__(self)


class TObject(gtk.Object):
    __gproperties__ = {
        "testproperty":
            (
                gobject.TYPE_STRING,
                "nick",
                "blurb",
                "value of test string",
                gobject.PARAM_READABLE
            )
    }
    __gsignals__ = {}

    def do_get_property(self, prop):
        if prop.name == "testproperty":
            return self.testproperty

    def do_set_property(self, prop):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        self.testproperty = ""
        gtk.Object.__init__(self)


gobject.type_register(TObject)


class TWidget(gtk.Widget, TObject, DummyClass):
    __gproperties__ = {
        "testproperty2":
            (
                gobject.TYPE_STRING,
                "nick",
                "blurb",
                "value of test string2",
                gobject.PARAM_READABLE
            )
    }
    __gsignals__ = {}

    def do_get_property(self, prop):
        if prop.name == "testproperty2":
            return self.testproperty2

    def do_set_property(self, prop):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        self.testproperty2 = "But it's right here."
        # TObject.__gobject_init__(self)
        # gtk.Widget.__gobject_init__(self)
        self.__gobject_init__()
        self.add_events(
            gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK |
            gtk.gdk.BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK
        )
        TObject.__init__(self)
        DummyClass.__init__(self)


gobject.type_register(TWidget)


class TWindow(gtk.Window, TWidget):
    __gproperties__ = {
        "testproperty3":
            (
                gobject.TYPE_STRING,
                "nick",
                "blurb",
                "value of test string3",
                gobject.PARAM_READABLE
            )
    }
    __gsignals__ = {}

    def do_get_property(self, prop):
        if prop.name == "testproperty3":
            return self.testproperty3

    def do_set_property(self, prop):
        pass

    def __init__(self, type=gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL, dummyarg=""):
        self.testproperty3 = dummyarg
        TWidget.__init__(self)
        gtk.Window.__init__(self)


gobject.type_register(TWindow)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def on_destroy(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            print "Trying to get testproperty2"
            print args[0].get_property("testproperty2")
        except TypeError:
            print "\tNo such property."
        print "Getting it from the associated variable..."
        print "\t", args[0].testproperty2
        print "Recognized properties are..."
        ct = 0
        base = "{:<20}{}\n\t"
        out = "\t"
        for x in args[0].props:
            ct += 1
            if ct % 2 == 0:
                out += base.format(x1, x.name)
                x1 = None
                continue
            else:
                x1 = x.name
        if x1 is None:
            print out
        else:
            print out, x1
        print (
            "NOTE: testproperty and testproperty2 do not appear in the list.\n"
            "      (Defined in TObject and TWidget respectively.)")
        gtk.mainquit()


    win = TWindow()
    l = gtk.Label("Just close me\nand watch the output.")
    win.add(l)
    win.connect("destroy", on_destroy)
    win.show_all()
    gtk.main()
```

Second code set:
OK, this stupid form wont let me put it in.  SO code set one only.

Comment: I have also subclassed Gtk + Python. I too have had problems (and still have). I really would like to see your code. Google searches have been almost helpless to me. If you have a project on Github or Sourceforge, I would enjoy helping you.

Comment: Just to be sure : why are you using pyGTK instead of pygobject ? Are you stuck with GTK+ 2 ?

Comment: using gtk2 by choice actauly...large project with lots of code I would have to change.

Comment: Considered the 2to3 script for the conversion (included with Python3)?